# Why wouldn't credit card reward auto-redemption offer statement credit?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, reward-program, bank-of-america

I see that with Bank of America, credit card reward redemption can be a statement credit:

[image]

unless it's auto-redemption:

[image]

Why wouldn't credit card reward auto-redemption offer statement credit?

Comment: Ask B0A, it's their policy... The obvious answer is that they're trying to get you to deposit more money into a BOA account.

Comment: @Franck just ask me these questions by DM on reddit or quora. It isn't a problem carrying a credit balance on a credit card. They aren't obliged to send you a check if you do! If you keep asking them to, they might get annoyed.

Comment: There are also rules about not using credit card funds to pay for credit cards within the same institution. It isn't a good idea to ever do that of course, but banks have internal rules against it and I can check if there is a self-regulating or even regulatory entity that disallows it (maybe, if you have a good reason for asking but it would take time for me to check).

Answer (score -5, accepted):

This [Reddit thread](https://redd.it/zhnw3p) mentions that credit balance may result in physical checks, which banks prefer to avoid. Quotes below.

---

Reddit user [Werewolfdad](https://www.reddit.com/user/Werewolfdad):

> Credit balance means sending endless statements and eventually cutting a physical check.

Reddit user [whisky_in_your_water](https://www.reddit.com/user/whisky_in_your_water):

> If it goes to statement credit, and there aren't enough charges to exceed that credit, the credit card company would need to send a check. If it's automated, this can happen a lot more.

Comment: This is a pure speculation.

Comment: @littleadv what part of the answer is speculative?

Comment: All of it. Reddit is not a reliable reference for BoA internal policies.

Comment: @littleadv the claim that banks prefer to avoid checks is not speculative at all.

Comment: It is. I've hit this exact scenario with multiple different banks (WF, Amex, Chase) and none of them had any issues sending a refund check for the negative balance.

Comment: @littleadv still, banks prefer ACH transfers over checks, since the former is cheaper. Do these banks offer credit card reward *auto*-redemption via checks?

Comment: You can check on their websites

Comment: @littleadv I checked for Chase and I don't see any  credit card reward auto-redemption via check.